# How do I test the type of the detail from a CustomEvent in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I hope you'll excuse what I expect is a real newbie question, but I haven't been able to find a good solution to this problem…

If I have a simple class...

```
library segmented_buttons_list;

import 'package:web_ui/observe.dart';

@observable
class SegmentedButtonData {
  String description;
  int index;

  SegmentedButtonData(this.description, this.index);

  String toString() => "$description";
}
```

… and dispatch an event from a WebComponent with that class in the detail...

```
library segmented_buttons_list;

import 'dart:html';
import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart';
import 'package:segmented_buttons_list/segmented_button_data.dart';

class SegmentedButtonComponent extends WebComponent {
  int index;
  String description;

  mainAction() {
    SegmentedButtonData detail = new SegmentedButtonData(description, index);
    CustomEvent event = new CustomEvent("MainActionEvent", canBubble: true, cancelable: true, detail: detail);
    print("SegmentedButtonComponent dispatching ${event.type} for '${event.detail}'.");
    dispatchEvent(event);
  }
}
```

… how do I properly test and use that detail as the intended type?

I tried using "is", but that didn't work when in an event handler...

```
if (event.detail is SegmentedButtonData) {
  SegmentedButtonData newSBD = event.detail;
  int newIndex = newSBD.index * 3;
  print(newIndex.toString());
}
```

… and when I commented out the "if" I got the error "type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'SegmentedButtonData' of 'newSBD'.".

I tried using "as", that didn't work either.

It seems the "detail" object is a String, even though I sent an instance of SegmentedButtonData.

Do I need to serialise/de-serialise, or am I missing some detail? (ha ha).

Comment: Strange. What's the value of the string `event.detail` in the handler?

Comment: @MarioP If I leave the toString() in SegmentedButtonData it's used, but if I comment it out I get "Instance of 'SegmentedButtonData'".

Comment: so do I understand that right... `event.detail == [your_button_data].toString()`? That's weird.

Comment: @MarioP I know, strange isn't it? I'll have to see if there are any bugs raised for this already, and if not get a small example together and raise it I think.

Comment: I think so. As a workaround, maybe you could wrap and unwrap the object with JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the Dart CustomEvent mechanism is built upon standard Web Browser events so that other code (JavaScript) outside of Dart can catch events, the detail of a CustomEvent is intentionally serialised.

This means for best predictability it is best to serialize the data for a CustomEvent detail payload manually so that you can deserialize with confidence.

In theory you can do this with the Serialization package, but it's over-kill and I still had problems deserializing, or you can do something as simple as use JSON (assuming your class properties are mainly strings, numbers, lists and maps).

The data class now has a `toJson()` function...

```
library segmented_buttons_list;

import 'package:web_ui/observe.dart';

@observable
class SegmentedButtonData {
  String description;
  int index;

  SegmentedButtonData(this.description, this.index);

  String toString() => "$description";

  Map toJson() {
    return {"description": this.description, "index": this.index};
  }
}
```

... we serialize the data object to JSON to add to the `CustomEvent`...

```
library segmented_buttons_list;

import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:json' as json;
import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart';

import 'package:segmented_buttons_list/segmented_button_data.dart';

class SegmentedButtonComponent extends WebComponent {
  int index;
  String description;

  mainAction() {
    SegmentedButtonData sbd = new SegmentedButtonData(description, index);
    String detail = json.stringify(sbd);
    CustomEvent event = new CustomEvent("MainActionEvent", canBubble: true, cancelable: true, detail: detail);
    dispatchEvent(event);
  }
}
```

... and deserialize for checking and using event detail when we handle the event...

```
Map detail = json.parse(event.detail);

if (detail is Map && detail.containsKey("description") && detail.containsKey("index")) {
  SegmentedButtonData newSBD = new SegmentedButtonData(detail["description"], detail["index"]);
  int newIndex = newSBD.index * 3;
  print(newIndex.toString());
}
```

Hope this is of help to someone.